# Twitter bootstrap alert change class

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created an alert in Twitter Bootstrap this way

HTML:

```
<div id='alert' class='hide'></div>
```

JS:

```
function showAlert(message) {
    $('#alert').html("<div class='alert alert-error'>"+message+"</div>");
    $('#alert').show();
}
showAlert('Please have a look at yourself.');
$('#alert').removeClass('alert-error');
$('#alert').addClass('alert-info');
```

But the last two lines of javascript don't seem to have any effects, can anyone have a look for me?

Created jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf4gs/).

**Update**
I made some changes in my own code to make it easier to use, I prefer this way

HTML:

```
<div id='alert' class='hide'></div>
```

JS:

```
function showAlert(message, alertType) {
  $('#alert').html("<div class='alert alert-"+alertType+"'>"+message+"</div>");
  $('#alert').show();
}

showAlert('Please have a look at yourself.', 'success');
```

New jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf4gs/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#alert div').removeClass('alert-error');
$('#alert div').addClass('alert-info');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cf4gs/2/

Comment: Nice! Why is that though?

Comment: @Juto because you were removing & adding the class of the parent div with `id=alert` not of the div you just inserted inside that div! this code will access the div inside the div with `id=alert`

Answer (score 1):

Last two javascript lines are working.

However you really wanted to do this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MartinTale/Cf4gs/1/)

```
$('.alert-error').removeClass('alert-error').addClass('alert-info');
```

Comment: I see this would do the `remove` and `add` to all the `.alert-error` elements, I think that's not very good.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#alert .alert').removeClass('alert-error').addClass('alert-info');
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the button to show the alert. What event causes the alert to pop-up or is the alert to be present always?
Also if you need to close the alert you need a button for that too.

For example -

```
<div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
        <strong>Sucess!</strong> Values updated!!
```

The Javascript to close the button -

```
$('.close').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('in'); // hides alert with Bootstrap CSS3 
});
```

Comment: I just want the alert show when the page loads. I don't want to close it.